# postman says that my action returns json but spec says that response body is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have a controller having some methods in it. let's call the main method which is called by route "start". I use postman chrome extension to get and post and now i get the associated route for that method and get correct result in json format.
I wanted to write spec test for my method and I got that route and checked its `response.body`  and it was empty! why?

by the way I'm rendering the template in my method like this: `return render 'parse_json_for_god_sake'` if it helps or differs.

Answer (score 0):

I found "render_views" and added it my spec and now it works.